# Django Datetime field question

Tags: django, datetime, view, models

Hello I have been having a problem with django while trying to work with datetime. In my webapp I have a table like so when I run server.

```
ID  Owing
1   -100   (All the same value)
2   -100
3   -100
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

It has in one column Invoice id and the other owing. One-one relationship as well. sow for example owing value for 1 is 100. Unfortunately, this is where it all goes wrong because throughout column (Owing), it is giving me the owing value for ID=1. I want each ID to give me their owing value.

Here is my view. I also wonder if I may need a for loop somewhere as well.

```
def homepage(request):
    invoices_list = Invoice.objects.all()
    invoice_name = invoices_list[0].client_contract_number.client_number.name
    invoice_gross = invoices_list[0].invoice_gross
    payment_date = invoices_list[0].payment_date
    if payment_date <= datetime.now():
        owing = invoice_gross
        if payment_date > datetime.now():
            owing = 0
        else: owing= 0
    return render_to_response(('index.html', locals()), {'invoices_list': invoices_list ,'invoice_number':invoice_number, 'invoice_name':invoice_name, 'invoice_gross':invoice_gross, 'payment_date':payment_date, 'owing': owing}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

EDIT: Here is my template. The thing is the function owing is not in my models so saying {{invoices.owing}} wont work.

```
  {% for invoices in invoices_list %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{invoices.invoice_number}}</td>
        <td>{{invoices.invoice_contact}}</td>
    <td>{{invoices.client_contract_number}}</td>
        <td>{{invoices.payment_date|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
        <td>{{invoices.invoice_gross}}</td>
    <td>{{owing}}</td>
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward: You define `owing` once in your view, then refer to it *in your loop* over and over.

According to your view, `owing` will always be `0` or `none` (I think you have your code indented incorrectly, since you have an `if foo: owing=0 else: owing=0`

Here's what I would do:

### Option 1: In the view

You can calculate owing for each item in your view by adding the calculated value to your object instance. It's a python object you can do anything to.

```
def homepage(request):
    invoices_list = Invoice.objects.all()
    invoice_name = invoices_list[0].client_contract_number.client_number.name
    invoice_gross = invoices_list[0].invoice_gross
    payment_date = invoices_list[0].payment_date

    def calculate_owing(invoice):
        if invoice.payment_date <= datetime.now():
            invoice.owing = invoice.invoice_gross
        else:
            invoice.owing = 0
        return invoice

    invoices_list = [calculate_owing(invoice) for invoice in invoices_list]
    return render_to_response(('index.html', locals()), {'invoices_list': invoices_list ,'invoice_number':invoice_number, 'invoice_name':invoice_name, 'invoice_gross':invoice_gross, 'payment_date':payment_date, 'owing': owing}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% for invoices in invoices_list %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{invoices.invoice_number}}</td>
        <td>{{invoices.invoice_contact}}</td>
        <td>{{invoices.client_contract_number}}</td>
        <td>{{invoices.payment_date|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
        <td>{{invoices.invoice_gross}}</td>
        <td>{{invoices.owing}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

### Option 2: In the model

Define a function to get `owing` in the model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model def

    @property
    def owing(self):
        if self.payment_date <= datetime.now():
            owing = self.invoice_gross
        else:
            owing = 0
        return owing
```

At which point the template would look exactly the same -- access owing by {{ myinstance.owing }}

Comment: You know what. This is exactly what I need. Finally it has done what I wanted to do, thanks ;).

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting the `owing` value for the *first* record. Look:

First, you get all the invoices:

```
invoices_list = Invoice.objects.all()
```

Good. But then, in `invoice_name`, you *slice* the list, and only take the first element (`invoices_list[0]`) and get the name from that. You do the same thing for `invoice_gross`:

```
invoice_gross = invoices_list[0].invoice_gross
```

See? You're only getting the `invoice_gross` for the first returned element (`invoices_list[0]`). You also only get the date for the first record:

```
payment_date = invoices_list[0].payment_date
```

Then you compare that date, and set `owing` to `invoice_gross`, which, again, is only the `invoice_gross` for the *first record*. Then you pass `owing` into the template.

Basically, in the template (or in the view, whichever is easiest/best), you have to loop through *each* record, and get the `owing` value for each individual record.

## Update

As shown in your template code, you are only using the value of `owing` for the *first* record. You'll probably need to write a [custom template filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that calculates `owing` given a record, so you can do:

```
<td>{{ invoices|owing }}</td>
```

Comment: Please have a look at my template to see if there my be a problem with the template. I think there may be a problem with the tag owing as it can't loop.